# How to place sticky ad bottom of the recyclervew?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, ads, sticky

I have placed ad bottom of the recyclerview but it doesn't  appear . When I scroll up then it appears. But I want to keep it sticky. How can I do it? Please help.

Similar this app.

[image]

Here is my layout,

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.tofabd.internetspeedmeter.ui.fragment.MonthFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/total_bar"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/id_titlebar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:weightSum="13">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:text="Date"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:paddingRight="2dp"
                    android:text="Wifi"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:paddingRight="2dp"
                    android:text="Mobile"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:text="Total"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/cardList"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:overScrollMode="never"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:clipToPadding="false" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/total_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_ad"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:weightSum="13">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:text="Total"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/id_wifi"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:text="Wifi"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/id_mobile"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:text="Mobile"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/id_total"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Total"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_ad"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home">

            </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is output, I want to keep the ad stikcy.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_titlebar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:weightSum="13">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:text="Wifi"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:text="Mobile"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="Total"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/id_titlebar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/total_bar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/cardList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:clipToPadding="false" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/total_bar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_ad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:weightSum="13"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Total"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id_wifi"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:text="Wifi"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id_mobile"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:text="Mobile"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id_total"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="Total"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_ad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: post screenshot

Comment: Placed ad in coordinator layout and added android:fitsSystemWindows= true which was false. now it's working.
anyway thanks bro.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CoordinatorLayout, Try adding android:fitsSystemWindows= true in CoordinatorLayout!

Comment: @tofa please accept the answer and upvote if my answer worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your .xml try it out

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_titlebar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:weightSum="13">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:text="Wifi"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:text="Mobile"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="Total"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/id_titlebar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/total_bar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/cardList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:clipToPadding="false" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/total_bar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_ad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:weightSum="13"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Total"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id_wifi"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:text="Wifi"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id_mobile"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:text="Mobile"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id_total"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="Total"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_ad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>

 </FrameLayout>
```